# Look-around assertions in atom.io regex finf-and-replace

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I've gotta find some pattern in a very large (> 440,000 lines) text file, which looks like this:

```
negative,10946,N: 10947,P: 59316,7.4346858,52.3209003
145930
24941,N: 54399,P: 24940,7.4308326,52.323004
145943

positive,57656,N: 57658,P: 57655,9.7569868,53.7176063
131516
57694,N: 57695
9.677158,53.6762726
131587
```

Or, in words, an integer number, after that a newline, and finally, another integer.

The problem lies the newline between lines #2 and #3 resp. #6 and #7: I must add a second \n here AND add the text "both,". I've managed to write a regex which finds the occurencies of such newlines in question:

```
^.[0-9]{4,7}\n[0-9]{4,7}
```

This regex finds all occurencies of such a newline. But: I don't really know what I should replace these text portions with. I wanna let the two numbers untouched, but insert a \n and "both," after the \n, which is already there.

Normally, I would use look-around assertions like this:

```
(?<=^.[0-9]{4,7})\n(?=[0-9]{4,7})
```

But: Apparently, atom.io does not support look-arounds, at least not in the syntax I'm used to. It just says, "Invalid group". Any hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after studying a similar SO question, I've found out that Atom supports Perl-style capturing group placeholders, so all I had to do, was to extend my RegEx like this:

```
(^.[0-9]{4,7})(\n)([0-9]{4,7})
```

…and to use this as a replacement string:

```
$1\n\nboth,$3
```

It's still a much more cumbersome syntax than look-arounds, but at least it works. :)